# Is it possible for an iOS app to control my device similarly to how Xcode can do it in UI Test?

Tags: ios

In a UI test I can easily control my device, include apps I don't own. For instance

```
let settingsApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Preferences")
settingsApp.launch()
```

will launch the Settings app.

Is it possible to run the same code, or to similarly control my device, from an iOS app instead of from Xcode? I would like to trigger automated workflows on my device without needing my laptop and Xcode.